# How to handle class with multiple data members of different type in c++?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

Suppose I have a class which has many data members of different type, and maybe add more in future

```
Class A
{
public:
   int getA();
   void setA(int a);
   ...
private:
   int m_a;
   int m_b;
   double m_c;
   string m_d;
   CustomerType m_e;
   char * m_f;
   ...

}
```

the problem is: each time I add a another data member, I need to add get/set function. For some reason I cannot change them to public.

one solution is to use getType/setType function together with template:

```
Class A
{
public:
   int getInt(int id){
      switch(id)
        case ID_A:
            return m_a;
        case ID_B:
            return m_b;
        ...
   }
   void setInt(int id,int i){...}
   double getDouble(){...}
   void setDouble(int id,double d){...}
   ...

   template<T>
   T get();
   template<> //specialize
   double get<double>(){return getDouble();}
   ...
private:

}
```

Is there any better solution? Thanks.

Comment: `For some reason I cannot change them to public.` If you want them public, make them public. Most IDEs have support for adding getters and setters. Tricks with templates / switches etc just confuse the code.

Comment: If you find yourself writing classes with many getters and setters, you should probably reconsider your design decisions.

Comment: `int getInt(int id)` um.. in *most* cases doing this only to cut down on your typing effort will (a) not actually accomplish that goal, since you need to add an ID *somewhere* that the caller is privy to, and (b) make for some absolutely hideous code to maintain. Stretch the fingers and declare your members as-appropriate.

Comment: Why can't you just add a getter+setter for every new member you add?

Comment: A class should *do* stuff rather than *have* stuff.

Comment: Data attributes should be private to minimize coupling.  Research Coupling and Cohesion.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN Making data members private is a necessary prerequisite for encapsulation, not a sufficient one.  If you go ahead adding getters and setters for every private member, all it has bought you is 100s of lines of boilerplate code.  Encapsulation is reached by good design, not by cheating around coding styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a strategy that works for me.

```
#include <string>

struct CustomerType {};

class A
{
   public:

      template <typename T> struct member
      {
         typedef T type;
         type data;
      };

      struct type_A : member<int> {};
      struct type_B : member<int> {};
      struct type_C : member<double> {};
      struct type_D : member<std::string> {};
      struct type_E : member<CustomerType> {};
      struct type_F : member<char*> {};

      template <typename T>
         typename T::type get()
         {
            return ((T&)allData).data;
         }

      template <typename T>
         void set(typename T::type d)
         {
            ((T&)allData).data = d;
         }

   private:

      struct AllData : type_A,
                       type_B,
                       type_C,
                       type_D,
                       type_E,
                       type_F {};

      AllData allData;
};

int main()
{
   A a;

   a.set<A::type_A>(20);
   int b = a.get<A::type_A>();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may use `static_cast` instead of C-cast.