# Does/would c++11/14 support something like vector<auto>

Tags: c++11, c++14

I am wondering if c++11/c++14 would/already support something like `vector<auto>`?
If not, Is there any reason?

Comment: How would it be used?

Comment: Maybe in C++999 so that you can `push_back` anything into the `vector`. :P

Comment: @cameron, with it We can write more generic code

Comment: @daman: I meant, can you provide an example? I'm not clear on what its semantics would be.

Comment: @cameron, here is an example:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26111448/how-to-handle-class-with-multiple-data-members-of-different-type-in-c

Comment: Well there is `std::vector< boost::any >` and `std::vector< boost::variant<type0, type1, type2, type_and_so_on> >`..

Answer (score 8):

It's not supported directly, and not immediately clear exactly what you want it to do.

Comments have already mentioned a couple of possibilities (such as Boost `any` and `variant` classes) for creating heterogeneous collections. I hope this isn't what you were after, because heterogeneous collections fit poorly with C++ so using them is ugly and clumsy. I suppose there are cases/situations where these really would be the best choices available, but at least in my experience, those cases are fairly rare.

Another possible interpretation of what you might want would be a vector that (like `auto` in general) holds exactly one type, but that type is deduced from the initializer, so if you initialized the vector from some `int`s, you'd get a `vector<int>`, and if you initialized it from some strings, you'd get a `vector<string>`, and so on. Although the language doesn't support that directly, it is pretty easy to simulate it to at least some degree. Template *classes* can't/don't ever deduce template parameters, but template *functions* do/can. Therefore, we can create a tiny function template to take some initializers, deduce their type, and return a vector of that type. For example:

```
template <class T>
std::vector<T> make_vector(std::initializer_list<T> init) {
    return std::vector<T>(init);
}
```

This returns a `vector<T>` (with `T` deduced from the type of data in the initializer list), so you can do things like:

```
auto a = make_vector({ 1, 2, 3, 4 });       // a -> vector<int>
auto b = make_vector({ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 });    // b -> vector<double>
auto c = make_vector({ "1"s, "2"s, "3"s }); // c -> vector<std::string>
```

That last one requires a user-defined literal operator that's new in C++14 (which many compilers don't yet support). The rest should be fine with C++11.

There has also been some discussion (and a proposal in [N3602](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3602.html)) of adding a capability (perhaps to C++17) where  you'd be able to define something like the `make_vector` above, but as something like a templated constructor for the class. This would let you use argument deduction on the constructor to deduce the template parameter for the class as a whole, so you'd be able to do something like:

```
X x(1);     // deduces as X<int>
X x(2.0)    // deduces as X<double>
```

Warning though: this has been proposed but not accepted. It may (easily) *never* be accepted--and even if it is, it may be altered significantly before that happens.

Comment: I believe the proposal you're thinking of is [N3602](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3602.html), which I don't think is going anywhere at the moment.

Comment: @dyp: After some thought (and a little reading) I think you're right--at least in this case (and maybe in general, though I'm less certain) passing by value undoubtedly makes the most sense (and I've edited accordingly).

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Thanks for the link--yes, that was the one I was thinking of (and I've edited the link into the answer, along with a little more strongly worded warning that it may never happen).

Answer (score 4):

No, not in C++11 or C++14, which are already finished and published.

But it's possible that `vector<auto>` and similar things like `tuple<auto...>` will be in C++17 as part of the Concepts work.

It follows quite naturally from the fact that `std::vector<T>` can be used in function templates and class template partial specializations where `T` is a template parameter, and also from the fact that polymorphic lambdas allow `auto` as a function parameter type (which is shorthand for a function template with deduced parameters).

The Concepts TS allows a "generic function" to be declared like:

```
auto func(auto arg);
```

Since you can have a function template like this:

```
template<typename T>
  auto func(std::vector<T> v);
```

it makes sense to extend the generic function syntax to allow:

```
auto func(std::vector<auto> v);
```

and once you allow that in a function declaration, it should also be possible to allow it in variable declarations:

```
std::vector<auto> v = function_returning_vector_of_something();
```

The reason it isn't in C++11 is that `auto` was new, and it would have been too ambitious to try and make it do too much. In C++14 polymorphic lambdas were new, and again, expanding the uses of `auto` any further would have been ambitious.

For C++17 we have more experience with using `auto` in real code, and compiler writers are familiar with implementing it and know what is possible without too much effort.

Comment: Are you saying that in C++17 the compiler will be able to deduce `T` for `std::vector<T>` from initializer_list? Currently `func({ 1, 2, 3, 4 })` doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not saying it _will_ be able to anything, it's too early to know for sure. The point of that example was not the initializer list though, but the use of `auto`, so I've changed that example.

Answer (score 1):

A `boost::any` can store an instance of any type that can be copied, which is a lot of types.

In order to get the data out of your `any`, you have to know the exact type you stored in it.

Writing a simple `any` isn't hard:

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

struct any_internal {
  virtual any_internal* clone() const = 0;
  virtual ~any_internal() {};
};
template<class T>
struct any_details;
class any {
  std::unique_ptr<any_internal> internal;
public:
  any() = default;

  any( any && ) = default;
  any( any const&& o):any(o) {}
  any( any & o ):any( const_cast<any const&>(o) ) {}

  any& operator=( any && ) = default;
  any& operator=( any const&& o ) { return this->operator=( o ); };
  any& operator=( any & o ) { return this->operator=( const_cast<any const&>(o) ); };

  any( any const& o ):internal( o.internal?o.internal->clone():nullptr ) {}
  any& operator=( any const& o ) {
    any tmp(o);
    using std::swap;
    swap( internal, tmp.internal );
    return *this;
  }

  template<class U>
  void reset( U&& o );
  template<class U, class... Args>
  void emplace( Args&&... args );
  template<class U>
  any( U&& o );
  template<class U>
  any& operator=(U&& o);
  template<class T> T* get();
  template<class T> T const* get() const;
  template<class T> T* fast_get();
  template<class T> T const* fast_get() const;
  explicit operator bool() const { return internal!=nullptr; }
};
template<class T>
struct any_details : any_internal {
  T t;
  template<class...Args>
  any_details( Args&&... args ):t(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
  any_internal* clone() const override { return new any_details<T>{t}; }
};
template<class U, class... Args>
void any::emplace( Args&&... args ) {
  internal.reset( new any_details<U>( std::forward<Args>(args)... ) );
}
template<class U>
void any::reset( U&& o ) {
  emplace<typename std::decay<U>::type>( std::forward<U>(o) );
}
template<class U>
any::any( U&& o ) {
  reset( std::forward<U>(o) );
}
template<class U>
any& any::operator=(U&& o) {
  reset( std::forward<U>(o) );
  return *this;
}
template<class T> T* any::get() {
  auto* r = dynamic_cast< any_details<T>* >( internal.get() );
  if (r) return &r->t;
  return nullptr;
}
template<class T> T const* any::get() const {
  auto* r = dynamic_cast< any_details<T>* >( internal.get() );
  if (r) return &r->t;
  return nullptr;
}
template<class T> T* any::fast_get() {
  auto* r = static_cast< any_details<T>* >( internal.get() );
  if (r) return &r->t;
  return nullptr;
}
template<class T> T const* any::fast_get() const {
  auto* r = static_cast< any_details<T>* >( internal.get() );
  if (r) return &r->t;
  return nullptr;
}
```

and a `std::vector<any>` behaves much like you might want a `std::vector<auto>` to do.

Increased efficiency can be achieved via small buffer optimizations (ie, store the `T` within the `any` if the `t` is small, instead of using the heap).

You'd probably also want to split `get` from `fast_get`, where `get` does a `dynamic_cast` and `fast_get` does a `static_cast`, again for efficiency.  (When you know for certain, you can `fast_get`)

Basically this is a gussied up `void*`.

Comment: Why the `any const&&` and `any&` copy ctors?

Comment: `swap( internal, tmp.internal );` or `internal = std::move(tmp.internal);`

Comment: @dyp I have a universal copy ctor & assignment, I was being explicit about not calling it when the rhs is an `any`.  And yes, a `move` would also work: I was doing copy-swap, then got lazy about implementing `void swap(any&, any&)` because I noticed it was 2 lines long.  Thanks for fixes -- was written off-the-cuff.

Comment: I wonder if you could implement the assignment as `any& operator=(any o) = default;` -- but I guess that's broken even in C++14, since it's a *copy* assignment-ctor and seems to perform member-wise *copy*.

Comment: @dyp oh god, that so needs to be fixed.

Comment: std-discussion? I remember Scott Meyers once complained about something related, but I think it had to be with being move-assignable when only having an `operator=(any)` but no `operator=(any&&)`

Comment: @dyp `any& operator=(any)=default` [does not seem to be valid syntax](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/298c1e2bbd588183), or is clang wrong?  Reading 8.4.2/1 `[dcl.fct.def.default]` seems like clang is right.  Making it legal seems reasonable: should it implicitly `swap` or `move`?

Comment: I'm not sure where you think [dcl.fct.def.default] says that we cannot have `any& operator=(any) = default`; [class.copy]/17 defines *copy assignment operator* as "A user-declared *copy* assignment operator `X::operator=` is a non-static non-template member function of
class `X` with exactly one parameter of type `X`, `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`." (I'm reading N3797, which is a bit old) I'd say *move* since `swap` is a library-only feature.

Comment: @dyp 12.8/18 " The implicitly-declared copy assignment operator for a class X will have the form `X& X::operator=(const X&)` if (condition) otherwise, the implicitly-declared copy assignment operator will have the form `X& X::operator=(X&)` " -- 8.4.2/1 "A function that is explicitly defaulted shall: ...  have the same declared function type (...) as if it had been implicitly declared ..." -- `foo& operator(foo)` is not the declared function type of any implicitly declared special member functions, so cannot be `=default`ed.  (The `(...)` clause talks about 2 exceptions, neither apply)